# Assign html to div by jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to use jQuery to assign the html content to div. I have used the code but it is not assigning the value to the div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#oneclickorder").click(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'modules/oneclickorder.php?divid=NFS',
            success:function(data){
               var onclickdata=data;
               $('#oneclickorder1').html(onclickdata);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: check `data`  with `console.log(data)` in firebug

Comment: are you sure the ajax call is returning any data? Try dumping the content of `data` in the console and see what is shows

Comment: you mean alert(console.log(data)). i am getting data when i alert(onclickdata)

Comment: yes ajax is returning the data. even i try to $('#oneclickorder1').html("heloo"); this is not working too

Comment: is `$('#oneclickorder1')` an id for an element?

Comment: If `$('#oneclickorder1').html("heloo");` isn't working, then there's a problem with your HTML.

Comment: there is a ; missing after ajax(...) and }); at the end

Comment: @Forte: can you please edit the code. i do not know where to ad this

Comment: I made the edit, I don't know if that's causing the problem though

Comment: @user1515728, check if your code works after the edit, because probably the syntax error was causing your issue

Comment: The edit MAY be the issue, thus if it IS the issue, the edit is invalid/improper and the answer by @Blazemonger would be correct.

Comment: hi Blazemonger: can you suggest me what kind of HTML error

Comment: @ Mark Schulthesis: can you suggest me what kind of HTML error

Comment: @user1515728 only one obligatory advice: Open the page in _Firefox_, click on the `#oneclickorder` button/link, press `Ctrl+Shift+i` ,hover with mouse over your target div `#oneclickorder1` and see, whether your ajax response is there or not.

Answer (score 1):

check if

```
$('#oneclickorder1').length
```

is bigger than 0.
probably the selector isn't returning any element

Comment: i used  alert($('#oneclickorder1').length);
it returned 1 . what does that mean?

Comment: it means the selector is correct. 
is your div visible? because everything looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

Check your console for JavaScript errors. You are missing a `});` at the end of your code, which may be the entire problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/MGeP3/

Comment: Did you get any other errors? Because the bracket-parenthesis IS needed.

Comment: i have checked there is nor bracket-paraenthesis needed. i insert another }); then it flattern my html page

Comment: Well, the code that's there appears to work fine in my fiddle. You need to track down exactly where the error is occurring if you expect us to help you further.